# Parsing XML in Python IO Error

Tags: python, xml

I understand this question has been asked (and answered) numerous times on stack. And I have tried a lot of them, but for some reason I can't get past this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\eclipse\workspace_python\TF2_Monitor\src\TF2_Monitor.py", line 23, in <module>
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(sampleXML)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1920, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 922, in parse
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>\n<Patients>\n    <Patient>\n               <PatientCharacteristics>\n                   <patientCode>3</patientCode>\n               </PatientCharacteristics>\n    </Patient>\n</Patients>'
```

This is the bit of code causing the problem:-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   from xml.dom import minidom

   sampleXML = """<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
   <Patients>
      <Patient>
           <PatientCharacteristics>
               <patientCode>3</patientCode>
           </PatientCharacteristics>
      </Patient>
   </Patients>"""


   xmldoc = minidom.parse(sampleXML)
```

From previous answers "No such file directory" implies it can't find the xml, but can that still be the case when I've declared it as a variable in the code? I'm guessing it's something simple but just cant spot it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`minidom.parse()` takes a **filename** (or a file object instead of a string), not the XML to parse.  Use [`xml.minidom.parseString()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parseString) instead:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(sampleXML)
```

Note that unless you are already familiar with the XML DOM standard, you probably do **not** want to use the `xml.minidom` package; as the documentation states:

> Users who are not already proficient with the DOM should consider using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module for their XML processing instead.

The DOM is, due to its cross-language nature, very verbose and does not make use of Python's strengths. Use the ElementTree API instead if you can; either with the standard library [`xml.etree.ElementTree` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), or with the (faster and more comprehensive) external [`lxml` library](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: I suggest to use `lxml` too.

Comment: @Markus: I have no problems parsing your sample XML with `minidom.parseString()`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and suggestions. I did try - `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`  <br/>`tree = ET.parse(sampleXML)`. Using the save xml string and still got the same error.

Comment: @Markus: same error; use `ET.fromstring()` to parse strings. `ET.parse()` takes a filename or file object. The documentation is quite clear on this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you must be chuckling watching be try and compose my comment :)

Comment: @Markus: I was too busy trying to format my *\`code in a comment example\`*.. We don't get notified of comment updates; you need to reload the page for those. So your edits were not visible in real time.

Comment: I'll have a play with all three options (minidom, lxml, ElementTree) to improve my general understanding and go with what clicks best. Your replies and help (particularly pointing out the methods need for a file instead of a string) have got me to parsing the xml so I should hopefully be able to nut out the rest. Thanks you all very much for your help and quick responses.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse a string, you will need to use [`minidom.parseString`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parseString) instead. [`minidom.parse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parse) expects either a file handle or a file name.

So do the following instead:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(sampleXML)
```